# IIS7: Why can't i Choose v3.5 .net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, .net-framework-version

The only choices for the application pools are .net 2.0 or 4.0, but my machine is running on 3.5.

I am currently getting a

*system.platformnotsupportedexeception*

in an app that i built, and i think it might be related to this issue.

Comment: 2 seconds in google yields: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx

Comment: i'll just use google instead of SO from now on, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind, there is no 3.5 version of the .NET runtime - only a 3.5 version of the .NET Framework.  The CLR itself is either 2.0 or 4.0.  Why they have weird versioning is beyond me (I guess there were no runtime modifications to support the 3.5 framework), but the framework versions are different than the runtime versions.

Comment: .NET 3.0 only brought library changes, while the modifications in .NET 3.5 were both compiler- and library-related. The runtime didn't need to be modified _at all_ for those two versions. The runtime was finally updated in .NET 4, mostly because of the DLR.

Comment: Yea sounds right.  Like 2.0 brought a bunch of compiler and runtime changes to support generics and stuff.  Then, they just worked on framework improvements for a while.  I think 4.0 has a bunch of changes to make interop with DLR languages possible, and perhaps some other improvements.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 has the same base runtime as .NET 2.0.  So in your case, selecting 2.0 is correct.

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858535/net-framework-version-issue).